Ignore outer wrapper
I am trying to ignore json outer wrapper for which I tried multiple json annotations like @JsonTypeInfo etc but nothing worked so far.
my json looks like:
 {"header":{},"body":[{"data":{"emp":[{"name":"abc","address":""},{"name":"xyz","address":""}]}}],"statusCodeValue":200,"statusCode":"OK"}

I want to ignore the wrapping "data" and "emp" and only get the List like this:
{"name":"abc","address":""},{"name":"xyz","address":""}

My java classes look like:
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class Employee{
String name;
String address;
}


@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class Employees{
@JsonProperty("emp")
List<Employee> employees;

}

I am trying to read value with the below:
Map<String ,?> body=restTemplateResponse.getBody();
Object response=body.get("body"); // returns arraylist of objects [{data={emp=[{name=abc,address=null},{name=xyz,address=null}]}}] 
ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
mapper.convertValue(response, new TypedReference<>(){});


Your JSON doesn't start with a "{"; please correct the typo. Also, what do you mean by "only get the list"? There are at least 2 lists that I can see there.

Thank you for pointing it out  I have fixed the typo.  I have made edits to the question to specify what i am looking for.

You can use readTree and select only the node that interests you:
    JsonNode node = objectMapper
            .readTree(jsonString)
            .get("body")
            .get(0)
            .get("data");
    Employees emps = objectMapper.convertValue(node, Employees.class);

Update:
Based on your update that body.get("body") "returns an arraylist of objects", and assuming that by "objects" you mean JSON objects rather than Java Object, then you can just do this:
Map<String, JsonNode> body = restTemplateResponse.getBody();
JsonNode response = body.get("body").get(0).get("data");
Employees emps = objectMapper.convertValue(node, Employees.class);


I have edited the question. getBody() returns arraylist

@fiddle an arraylist of what? Strings? JsonNodes? Maps?

Array list of objects

I am sorry for the confusion they are java object and not json

I get your point  I am able to traverse the list and get the data node. Thanks a bunch for the answer and edit. You really saved the day.

No worries, I'm glad I was able to help, despite my wrong assumption about "objects".
